# VS2013 Remote Debugging: How to find the relevant process?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am running several ASP.NET websites on my server. Attaching the remote debugger to the relevant process is always a lottery, since all process are called w3wp.exe.

[image]

In order to find the relevant process, right now I am helping myself by setting each application pool's Identity = ApplicationPoolIdentity (instead of the default NetworkService). This leads to a unique User Name in the list of processes (last column in my screen shot).

I was just wondering if there is a way to assign a title to a certain process (middle column in my screenshot...surprisingly always empty)? Maybe something in the settings of my VS project?

Thanks guys!